# Fuzzy figures - LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I seem to be having trouble inserting images and have them render clearly. Below is a figure where i just used,

```
 \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{NormalizedNoise.png}
    \caption{Normalised noise}
    \label{fig:NormalizedNoise.png}
 \end{figure}
```

[image: Unspecified dimensions]

Of course, this just inserts the image as the same size as the screenshot. So.. I try to crop it to a nice size using,

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=120mm, height=100mm]{NormalizedNoise.png}
    \caption{Normalised noise}
    \label{fig:NormalizedNoise.png}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Dimensions specified]

This fits nicely on the page, but it's blurry. They are both blurry... Why? I can understand that selecting arbitrary widths and heights for the image will cause it to be blurry, but i don't understand why the figure without specified dimensions also blurry.

How to scale them correctly? Many thanks.

Comment: Use vectorized graphics instead of png

Comment: Alternatively, can you re-save the png files at a higher resolution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. By which program is drawn those images?

Comment: The images are from MATLAB. And i have screenshotted the pdf produced by TeXStudio. I'll look into saving as higher resolution. But i don't really see why this is a problem. MSWord seems to manage fine? Not that i want to give them any credit.

Comment: First of, don't give height AND width, unless you know that they form the exact ratio of the image, you are might better of setting just the width (the height will then be scalled with the same resulting factor) or add the `keepratio` option. Without it the image will be distorted kbut perhaps not to the level you show here)

Comment: See if you can attach one of the png images here. It is almost certainly either very small or blurred.

Answer (score 3):

This should probably be a comment (and probably in some other forum) but it will not fit. You refer to your graphics as the screenshot. Hopefully that is not the case, you should use `print` in MATLAB to export your plots. It it is going to be used in LaTeX it is preferred to have it as pdf instead of png. The reason is that png is typically a compressed version of the picture in pixels. When scaling it you often have these blurry effects. Pdf is a vectorized picture that can be scaled.

Now, in MATLAB if you just write `print -dpdf FigName.pdf` you typically get an A4 with your picture centered. This is not what you want when it should be included. To remove all the white space I usually use the following script

```
function [] = PrintFigaspdf(FigH,FileName)
%%%%
% 
% Print fig
% 
% > PrintFigaspdf(gcf,'PlotName.pdf')
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%
set(FigH,'PaperOrientation','landscape');
set(FigH,'PaperUnits','normalized');
set(FigH,'PaperPosition', [0 0 1 1]);
print('-dpdf',FileName)
```

Save as `PrintFigaspdf.m` in the same directory and call with e.g. `PrintFigaspdf(gcf,'PlotName.pdf')`. Then you get a pdf that is suitable for inclusion in LaTeX.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for this. I've found the easiest solution is to save the MATLAB images as .eps files. This renders them clearly, and then from there (as others have said) only editing the width or height works out good.